# Real life example of motor/piston involving an isoterm process?

Tags: motors, compressed-gases, pistons, aviation

So I am involved in an introductory course in mathematics for pilots. I have the following problem I would like to give them, as it can be a practical application of integration

---

[image]

---

However, does there exists -- however how rudimentary -- real life example where such a process naturally occur? I was thinking about Reciprocating engine / piston engine for example Wright R-3350 Duplex-Cyclone which was used during the second world war. However, I am not sure that the process that occurs in the piston is actually an isoterm process.

- *So my question is does there exists a real life example of an engine / piston / motor (preferably related to aviation) which can relate to the problem above?*

Comment: So "you are involved in" means you teach it... Only when you have to teach something do you realize you did not fully understand it before.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes my background is theoretical physics and mathematics. I know very little about engines, pistons motors sadly.

Answer (score 1):

We assume isothermal as having to include all the heat gains and losses to the gas during the cycle would be too onerous and add little to the accuracy of the result.